# exception in remotewebdriver

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to run my test scripts in my virtual machine. I'm using `selenium server 2.34.0`. Any help will be appreciated...
    but i m getting an exception like this....

> [TestNG] Running:
>   C:\Users\nivid\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1565064710\testng-customsuite.xml

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeSuite beforesuite
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Parameter 'targetBrowser' is required by @Configuration on method beforesuite but has not been marked @Optional or defined
in C:\Users\nivid\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1565064710\testng-customsuite.xml
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:155)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:355)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createConfigurationParameters(Parameters.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:199)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:277)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:87)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1022)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:109)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:202)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:173)

SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest beforeTest
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod beforemethod
SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod aftermethod
SKIPPED: COPclientsearchTest

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
    Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 3
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 3
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@1e31bc4b: 70 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [TestListenerAdapter] Passed:0 Failed:0 Skipped:0]: 25 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter@1151000a: 8 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@52395294: 16 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@2786bf64: 13 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@3d78aa0f: 56 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may need to add the targetBrowser config to the xml...

```
<suite name="mySuite" verbose="2" thread-count="5">
<parameter name="targetBrowser" value="FIREFOX" />
```